# WaitForExit sometimes (randomly) doesn't work

Tags: c#, waitforexit

The code (only part) works properly most of the time, but it sometimes just hang there and the lines after try...catch block seem not to be called even if the process in the task manager doesn't exist any more.

Because most of the time there's just no problem with it, I can't reproduce the issue while debugging. Can any one give me a hint why or on what condition will this happen?

```
try {
    process.Start();
    process.BeginOutputReadLine();
    process.BeginErrorReadLine();
    process.WaitForExit(settings.PlinkConnectTimeout * 1000);
    if (process != null && !process.HasExited) {
        if (IsConnected) {
            process.WaitForExit();
        }
        else {
            process.Kill();
        }
    }
}
catch { }

IsConnected = false;
IsConnecting = false;
Disconnected(isLastSuccess, isReconnect);
```

Comment: How do you know that the lines after try-catch block are not called?

Comment: I can't promise that. But if they are called, some UI changes should have been triggered.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ProcessStartInfo hanging on "WaitForExit"? Why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/139593/processstartinfo-hanging-on-waitforexit-why)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/439617/hanging-process-when-run-with-net-process-start-whats-wrong

Comment: Seems not to be the same issue, as I am using BeginOutputReadLine and BeginErrorReadLine.