# Tasklist process don't terminate after its execution

Tags: c#, mono

I'm running this code snippet:

```
_taskListProcess = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = "/C tasklist /FO CSV /NH";
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
_taskListProcess.StartInfo = startInfo;
_taskListProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
_taskListProcess.Exited += new EventHandler(HandleTaskListProcessTerminated);
_taskListProcess.Start();
```

My issue is that the tasklist process never terminate.  I see it dangling in the Window task manager.  Therefore, my function  HandleTaskListProcessTerminated is never called.

I'm developing on Unity which uses Mono.

Comment: Since you are redirecting the output, a buffer gets full. Try to take the proach mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/q/439617/27083 to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The started process fills the StandardOutput buffer since you set `RedirectStandardOutput = true;`.
Try to read from `StandardOutput` until you consumed everything:

```
_taskListProcess.Start();
while (!_taskListProcess.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
{
    Console.WriteLine(_taskListProcess .StandardOutput.ReadLine());
}
```