# Process.Start hangs on Server 2012

Tags: c#, windows

I can find a lot of threads discussing Process.Start but none which sound like mine.  The code below has been working for years on Windows Server 2003 & 2008.  I'm now trying to install the same application on 2012 but although "My.exe" starts, Process.Start itself hangs - so "Started" is never logged.  Can anybody suggest what the issue might be?

Many thanks in advance,

Michael

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo("C:\\My.exe");
psi.UseShellExecute = false;
psi.LoadUserProfile = false;
psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
psi.ErrorDialog = false;
if (Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major >= 6) psi.Verb = "runas";
psi.Arguments = "\"MyArgs\"";
psi.RedirectStandardError = true;
psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
_logger.Info("Starting");
_process = Process.Start(psi);
_logger.Info("Started");
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the same thing as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439617/hanging-process-when-run-with-net-process-start-whats-wrong?rq=1)?

Also assuming that

> "C:\My.exe"

is a typo = "C:\\My.exe" or @"C:\My.exe"

Comment: Sorry, yes that was a typo.

Comment: The link there, if I understand it correctly, is a problem where WaitForExit hangs.  I'm not using that method and couldn't use it - as I'd need a Process object first, which I'm not getting as Process.Start never returns.

Comment: I dumped your sample into a WinForm app and ran it under a Server 2012 VM - replaced My.exe with cmd.exe and removed the Argument. The code works both as administrator and a normal user - maybe there is a problem with the "My.exe" program?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the "runas" verb to interactively demand administrative permissions only works when ProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute=true, assuming that the app does run interactively and you want the use to be prompted to approve an adminstrative action.  If not you might look into demanding the permissions from a [manifest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx).

Have you tried wrapping your _process = Process.Start(psi) in a try/catch and logging any exceptions?

Have you tried dropping this code into a console app with both of the RedirectStandard ... to false to see what happens?

Comment: This application is running on a server.  There is no user.  The "runas" is working fine on Server 2008.

Comment: It is wrapped in try {} catch {}.  There is no exception.

Comment: Dropping the RedirectStandardOuput/Error has no effect.

Comment: Low level security changes in 2008 vs 2012? Is UAC configured the same on both the server 2008 and 2012?  Give the [manifest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx) a try.